# Is it possible to override the Excel Data Type through SSIS?

Tags: sql, excel, types, ssis

I've tried finding a solution for my issue but alas the problem continues. I've got an Excel Data Destination which I am trying to map in to SSIS *[Please note I am saying the issue with the way SSIS identifies the Data Type of the Excel input. The scenario is `OLE DB Source > Data Conversion > Excel Destination`, please don't tell me to do a Data Conversion or use the Input and Output Properties method because it doesn't work, it just converts back to what SSIS "thinks" it's meant to be the instant I click out of the operations window]*. I'm trying to create a new Excel Document through SSIS by mapping out the template to my data source from OLE DB Source.

Now when I do it with example data in the Excel Destination, it works fine because SSIS registers that the value in the workbook is a NTEXT *[which is what I want]*. However, the instant I apply the expression to use a blank template *[with just headers no example data]*  it converts the Data Type in my Template to NVARCHAR(255) which is wrong and my package fails when I execute it, due to incompatible Data Type.

I've tried converting the Data Type within the Excel workbook to a TEXT format but it doesn't matter because when you pull it in to the Data Flow SSIS overwrites it and identifies that Column as a NVARCHAR(255). Even when I give up and comply and change the Input Data to NVARCHAR(255) because I'm just so annoyed, it still doesn't work because it fails my package and gives me an error message that it truncates my column field [-_-"]. I can't win.

I'll probably try and use a SQL Command to force it to identify the column as a NTEXT in the Excel Destination Editor or just rewrite some form of Forced SSIS to identify the Column as NTEXT but is there another way I am not aware of? I feel this is quite a known issue and there should be a plausible solution. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I've never found a way. It's suprising but the excel / jet / ace driver is a terrible driver, which is strange since it's for the MS flagship product (Excel). The driver is inflexible and basically useless. If I ever need to do excel integration now, I use powershell.  http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PSExcel-Intro/

Comment: Instead of the PS way, I read it in via the [ACE/JET drivers](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/ssis-excel-source-via-script.html) as that gives me ultimate control but at the cost of not using OOB componentry. As Nick rightly says, Excel and SSIS are not friends.